# Memoizing goals in Prolog

Tags: prolog, memoization

Is it possible for Prolog to memoize computed goals?

By that I mean to say that Prolog should not recompute goals that were computed before.

So, for example, the same computations for me are:

```
goal([first, one], he, she, var(cat, 5)).
goal([first, one], he, she, var(cat, 5)).
```

but not

```
goal([first, one], he, she, var(cat, 6)).
```

So, in fact, it must be possible to unify that goals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many Prolog systems provide the ability to *implicitly* record such results. This is called **tabling**; see your Prolog system's documentation about how to enable it.

A nice thing about Prolog is that you can easily build a somewhat simpler (and much less powerful) variant of tabling yourself, using for examlpe `assertz/1` to store and load computed results.

A very simple-minded implementation could look similar to:

```
:- dynamic memo_/1.

memo(Goal) :-
    (    memo_(Goal) -> true
    ;    Goal,
         assertz(memo_(Goal))
    ).
```

*Caveat emptor...*

That's of course not what full-fledged tabling will give you.

Comment: The problem appear because I have to compute goal with recursive subgoal. And every subgoal has a list and depends on that to fail or not. This list should be global in that sense, that if one subgoal append something there, the another subgoal sees it. But the problem is with backtracking- it undo everything. How to deal with it?

Comment: As always: You pass around the lists you need to reason about **as arguments** to all predicates that need it. And yes, backtracking undoes all bindings, which is kind of the point.

Comment: Ok, but what about situation when I would like to keep a list through backtracking. I know that the backtracking is the base/keypoint in Prolog but how to deal with such situations?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I.e., why are you using backtracking when you want to preserve the data? A simple solution in your case may be to simply *not* backtrack, or do so only in an auxiliary predicate.

Comment: Probably my approach to solution my problem is not proper. I have to think again.

Comment: @Gilgamesz would you be able to create a simple example of what you're trying or wanting to do?